# Rendering problem with Neon lights - Blender guru tutorial

Tags: rendering

Complete beginner here, I've been working on making neon lights from Blender Guru's tutorials and it looked pretty good on my viewport.

[image: Viewport]

However, when I tried to render it there was a dark halo around the pipe  material that didn't go away even when I disabled a few nodes in the shading workspace.

[image: Rendered]

I couldn't find people having the same problems on the comments section either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the duplicate of the original, flat text object still visible. You can delete it, hide it from the render or put it in a collection you disable with the checkbox. I hope that this is clear enough, otherwise just ask me your remaining questions.